# displaying image from image array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code i have below tries to display images from an image array but fail to display in ul of html tag.

it uses javascript to set width and height of image. and jquery to call display all image function.

how to correct it to display image from image from image array?

```js
var backgroundImage = new Array(); 
backgroundImage[0] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
backgroundImage[1] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
backgroundImage[2] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
backgroundImage[3] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
backgroundImage[4] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
backgroundImage[5] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
backgroundImage[6] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";

function displayAllImages() {
    var i = 0,
        len = backgroundImage.length;        
    for (; i < backgroundImage.length; i++) {
        
        var img = new Image();
        img.url = backgroundImage[i];
        img.style.width = '200px';
        img.style.height = '200px';
        
        document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
    }
};

$(function() {
    displayAllImages();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

    <div class="backgoundImage">
        <ul id="images"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `img.src` instead of `img.url`.

```js
var backgroundImage = new Array(); 
   //Use a loop instead
   // backgroundImage[0] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
   // backgroundImage[1] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
   // backgroundImage[2] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
   // backgroundImage[3] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
   // backgroundImage[4] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
   // backgroundImage[5] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";
   // backgroundImage[6] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random";

//omit the last query param if all images are to be the same
for(var j = 0; j <= 6; j++){
   backgroundImage[j] = "https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random&img="+j;
}
function displayAllImages() {
    var i = 0,
        len = backgroundImage.length;        
    for (; i < backgroundImage.length; i++) {
        
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = backgroundImage[i];
        img.style.width = '200px';
        img.style.height = '200px';
        
        document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);
    }
};

$(function() {
    displayAllImages();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

    <div class="backgoundImage">
        <ul id="images"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors

Comment: thanks now i understand, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Image_loading_errors